# ggplot multiple lines in same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to plot multiple gene expressions over time in the same graph to demonstrate a similar profile and then add a line to illustrate the mean of total for each timepoint (like the figure 4b in recent Nature comm article https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-02546-5/figures/4). My data has been normalised to be around 0 so they are all on the same scale.

df2 sample:

```
variable    value   gene
1   5   -0.610384193    1
2   5   -6.25967087 2
3   5   -3.773389731    3
50  6   -0.358879035    1
51  6   -6.066341017    2
52  6   -4.202998579    3
99  7   -0.103885903    1
100 7   -6.648844687    2
101 7   -5.041554127    3
```

I plot the expression levels with ggplot2:

```
plotC <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=factor(gene), colour=gene)) + geom_line(size=0.5, aes(color=gene), alpha=0.4)
```

But adding the mean line in red to this plot is proving difficult. I calculated the means and put them in another dataframe:

```
means
       value variable gene
1 -1.5037354        5   50
2 -0.8783492        6   50
3 -0.7769085        7   50
```

Then tried adding them as another layer:

```
plotC + geom_line(data=means, aes(x=variable, y=value, color="red", group=factor(gene)), size=0.75)
```

But I get an error `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can plot this mean on the same graph in another color?

Thank you,
Anna

edit: the answer by RG20 is helpful, thanks for pointing out I had the color in the wrong place. However it plots the line outside the rest of the graph... I really don't understand what's wrong with my graph...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWIVw.png)

Comment: You need to take `color = "red"` outside of the `aes` call.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to solve my error problem, however the line is drawn outside the rest of the graph area. I can't see why it would do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plotC + geom_line(data=means, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=factor(gene)), color='red',size=0.75)
```

Comment: thank you very much, that draws the line, but it puts it outside the other graph areas... it's weird, have a look at the linked photo I put in my original post

Comment: @Stav Sounds like your `variable` column is a `factor` in your original data and a `numeric` in your `means` data. If you convert `df2$variable = as.numeric(as.character(df2$variable))` this should work just fine.